# Dedicated mail server versus application servers sending out mail

Tags: apache-2.2, postfix

I just set up two new virtual CentOS machines that are going to act as our application servers (Apache only). What is the best practice in this situation?

Should I configure both these virtual machines to be able to send out email (they do run web apps after all and are going to be generating email notifications and such), or should I be using a dedicated mail server?

In our CURRENT set up, mysql/postfix/apache all reside on the same machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you want to go through the hassle of ensuring that each mailserver has a valid PTR record and is listed in your SPF config correctly, then I'd recommend that you set up centralized mail hub, through which all of your other servers send their mail. This could live on a third VM or could co-exist on on of your application servers if need be.

Comment: What if I'm okay with going through the hassle? They already have valid PTR records and I'm comfortable adding them to SPF.

Comment: Well then go for it. Though I should say that unless very high load is anticipated, I always prefer having a single outbound mail hub - only one place to look for logs, only one place to re-configure things if need be, etc.

Comment: Your one-log-file-to-rule-them-all sealed the deal for me.

Comment: Most Unix software assumes that it there is a local facility for routing mail - it's a good idea to setup an MTA using the hub as a smarthost, or a simple CLI to SMTP converter like nullmailer.